# How can I populate a comboBox using the fields in an excel column? C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, combobox

I have data in column B of my excel sheet that I would like to use to populate a combobox, each cell in the row being a value in the comboBox dropdown list.

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\\Private\\Users\\Temp\\testexcel.xlsm");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.Range["B1:B40"];



        foreach (var d in xlRange)
        {

           comboBox1.Items.Add(d);


        }
```

My code doesn't seem to work, I am having trouble with where I should be casting to a string so that it doesn't return as a system.COMobject and instead returns with all the strings in the excel cells as the values in the comboBox. Should I use an array or a list or neither? Am I getting the column range correctly?

Comment: This is probably very inefficient as the range will include ALL rows of column B - over 1million. If you know the data stops at the first blank cell, it would be better to avoid creating a massive list & just iterate through the cells with a for loop until you get a null value. As Jazimov says - you should use d.Value (or d.Value2). If you do iterate through the Cells property - you should note that although it is accessed as an array, the first value is Cells[1,1] not Cells[0,0]

Comment: I've edited my code to have a specific range (B1-B40), instead of the entire column. The combo box populates with items but each item just says System.COM Object, instead of the real value. I tried using "comboBox1.Items.Add(d.Value);" like Jazimov says but it gives an error "object does not contain a definition for Value". Can you please take a look at my edited code above? I'm thinking I need to somehow convert all the objects to a proper array or to strings or something.

Comment: nevermind I have figured out a way to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `d` to the `comboBox1`, does it work if you add `d.Value`, like this?

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(d.Text);
```

( You might need to cast to string although the .Text property already should return a string:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add((string)d.Text);
```

)

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't seem to work, I think my issue is earlier in the code, with how I am grouping the range and iterating over it in my foreach(). Perhaps I'm putting it into the list wrong or should not be using a list all together

Comment: @NicolePinto: see my comment above about using a list - creating the list will take a long time & use a lot of memory.

Comment: I think my version will work with.Text instead. I was unable to test the code when I posted it, but based on your working version, the .Text property should work. If you can try that and let us know, it might help others.

Comment: @Jazimov I posted what worked for me down below. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, I had to fix up some of the excel naming conventions in my foreach statement and convert them to strings within the statement!

```
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\\Private\\Users\\Temp\\testexcel.xlsm");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1]; 
            Excel.Range range = xlWorksheet.get_Range("B1:B40");


        foreach (Excel.Range item in range.Cells)
        {

            string lst = (string)item.Text;
            comboBox1.Items.Add(lst);
        }
```